# Equivalent definition of minimal spanning tree

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, spanning-trees, minimum-spanning-tree

> Prove that $T$ is MST $\Leftrightarrow$  for any edge $uv \notin T$, $uv$ has the maximal weight on the cycle created by adding $uv$ to $T$.

It's my attempt to prove $\Rightarrow$:
Consider the cycle $path(v, u) \in T \cup E(v, u)$. If $(v, u)$ is not maximal, replace the maximal edge on the path by $(v, u)$. T is still connected, and we got spanning tree which weight is less than $w(T)$.

But I am stuck with the direction of "$\Leftarrow$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* The original answer has a flaw in "without loss of generality". The following one is based on Section 8.2.3 of the book "Computer Algorithms" (3rd edition) by Sara Baase and Allen Van Gelder.

---

The right part of the theorem is called the MST property.

> *MST Property:* Let $T$ be any spanning tree. For any edge $e \notin T$, $e$ has the maximal weight on the cycle created by adding it to $T$.

In terms of the MST property, the theorem to prove can be restated as:

> A spanning tree $T$ is an MST $\iff$ $T$ has the MST property.

---

We first prove the following lemma:

> *Lemma:* If $T$ and $T'$ are spanning trees that have the MST property, then $w(T) = w(T')$.

*Proof:* Let $\Delta E = (E(T) \setminus E(T')) \cup (E(T') \setminus E(T))$. That is, $\Delta E$ is the set of edges that are in one of $T$ or $T'$ but not in both. $\Delta E \neq \emptyset$. Let $|\Delta E| = k$.

If $k = 0$, we are done.

Let $k > 0$ and $e$ be a minimum edge in $\Delta E$. Assume that $e \in T \setminus T'$ (the case of $e \in T' \setminus T$ is symmetrical).

$T' + e$ create a cycle $C_{T'}$. There must be an edge $e'$ on the cycle $C_{T}$ that $e' \neq e$ and $e' \in T' \setminus T$ (otherwise $T$ contains the cycle $C_{T'}$).

- Since $T'$ has the MST property, $e$ has the maximum weight on the cycle $C_{T'}$. Thus, $w(e') \le w(e)$.
- On the other hand, $e$ by definition is a minimum edge in $\Delta E$. Thus, $w(e) \le w(e')$.

Therefore, $w(e) = w(e')$.

Add $e$ to $T'$, creating a cycle, then remove $e'$, leaving a spanning tree $T''$. Since $w(T'') = w(T')$, $T''$ is an MST. However, $T$ and $T''$ differ by $k-1$ edges.

Repeating the procedure above, we will end with an MST, say $T^{k+1}$, such that $T$ and $T^{k+1}$ differ by $0$ edges.

Therefore, we have $w(T) = w(T^{k+1}) = \cdots = w(T'') = w(T')$.

---

Given the lemma above, we proceed to prove the "$\Leftarrow$" direction as follows:

Assume $T$ has the MST property. Let $T_m$ be any MST. By the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, $T_m$ has the MST property. By the lemma above, $w(T) = w(T_m)$. Thus, $T$ is an MST.

Comment: Why in the proof of the lemma T' is MST?  We haven't assumed that.

Comment: @sooobus Sorry. It was a mistake I have not corrected when I updated the answer.  It only relies on the fact that "$T'$ has the MST property".

Comment: Could you please explain, why when we substitute e' by e the MST property doesn't break

Comment: @sooobus That is because $w(e) = w(e')$.

Comment: But the new edge can form another set of cycles, and it they can not have the property

Comment: @sooobus If any edge $e''$ has the *maximal* weight on the cycle created by adding $e''$ to some spanning tree $T'$ (the original one), then it also has the *maximal* weight on the cycle (if exists) created by adding $e''$ to the spanning tree $T''$ ($T'' = T' + e - e'$) because $T'$ and $T''$ differ only by $e$ and $e'$ and that $w(e) = w(e')$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $T$ and $T''$ differ by $k-2$ edges, not $k-1$, since now both have $e$ and neither has $e'$?

Comment: @soobus This did not seem trivial to me and hengxin's comment did not convince me. It is essentially equivalent to the following lemma: "Let $T$ have the MST property and $e\in E\setminus T$.
Let $C\subset T\cup \{e\}$ be the cycle introduced by $e$'s addition to $T$.
Let $f\in C\cap T$ (so that in particular $f\neq e$) be an edge with $w(f) = w(e)$.  
Then $T' = (T\cup\{e\})\setminus\{f\}$ has the MST property.". It took me a while to prove this to be entirely honest, and I can provide the proof if you're interested.

Comment: @xdavidliu You are correct, but what matters for the induction is that $k$ decreases strictly until it reaches $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is a minimum spanning tree $T'$ with smaller weight than $T$. Since $T\neq T'$ there has to be an edge $uv$ in $T'$ but not in $T$. Now remove $uv$ from $T'$. This splits $T'$ into two trees $T'_u$ and $T'_v$. We denote the vertices spanned by $T'_u$ by $U$ and the vertices spanned by $T'_V$ by $V$. Let $\pi$ be the path that connects $u$ with $v$ in $T$. When traveling along $\pi$ we will leave at some point the set $U$ and enter the vertex set $V$. Assume that this "jump" happens at edge $ab$. Since $uv$ has a larger weight than $ab$ we get that $T'\setminus \{uv\} \cup \{ab\}$ has a smaller weight than $T'$ (and is of course a spanning tree). Hence $T'$ cannot be a MST and we have a contradiction to our assumption that there is a spanning tree with smaller weight than $T$.

Comment: Why is that "$uv$ has a larger weight than $ab$"? I do not get it.

Comment: @hengxin Well, $\pi$ with $uv$ forms a cycle, with all the edges of this cycle from $T$ except $uv$. Then by the assumption the weight of $uv$ is larger than any weight of the other edges in this cycle. Since $ab$ is in this cycle we get that the weight of $uv$ is larger than the weight of $ab$.

Comment: However, the edges with the maximal weight (on the cycle) may not be unique. I think we can only conclude that $w(uv) \ge w(ab)$.