# Are edges in a minimum spanning tree not heavier than respective edges in another spanning tree?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

Let $G$ be an undirected connected weighted graph, and let $T$ be a minimum spanning tree of $G$ with edge weights: $w_1 \le w_2 \le ... \le w_{n-1}$.

Now let $T'$ be some other spanning tree of $G$ (doesn't have to be minimum) with edge weights: $w'_1 \le w'_2 \le ... \le w'_{n-1}$.

I need to prove\disprove the following claim: for every $i$:  $w_i \le w'_i$.

I've tried to find a counterexample, but I wasn't successful. So I'm quite sure the claim is correct. However, I had trouble to prove it formally.

I assume the contrary, which means there is an $i$ that satisfies $w'_i < w_i$ and I take the first one that does. I tried adding it to the tree $T$ or trying to find a minimum spanning tree with this edge using Kruskal, but no luck.

Comment: Well I wasn't sure how to phrase it in the title, but it means that there is an edge weight $w'_i < w_i$ in $T'$

Comment: And I need to formally prove that such thing cant happen

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. Flesh out your counterexample with quantifiers properly: "There exists a graph $G$, and a minimum spanning tree $T$ for $G$ with edge weights $w_1 \le w_2 \le \dots \le w_{n-1}$, and another spanning tree $T'$ of $G$ with edge weights $w'_1 \le w'_2 \le \dots \le w'_{n-1}$, and an integer $i$ obeying $1 \le i \le n-1$, such that $w'_i < w_i$".  In a situation like this, from the set of all such counterexamples ($(G, T, T', i)$ tuples), you are free to choose one having minimum possible $i$, and it's nearly always useful (and never harmful) to do so.
2. "I tried adding it to the tree $T$" -- you must first show that it is not already in $T$.  Here you can use minimality of $i$ for edges to the left, and the increasing weight order for edges to the right.
3. Let's add it to $T$, to make a graph I'll call $G_2$.  What noticeable feature does $G_2$ contain?
4. What simple modifications could you make to that feature in $G_2$ to turn it back into a tree?  Hint: With this particular feature, there will always be at least 3 ways to do this, and there could be as many as $n$.
5. Can you choose an option in the previous step that will lead to a tree that is strictly lighter than $T$, and thus a contradiction (since we assumed $T$ to be minimal)?

Comment: So $G_2$ will have a cycle

Comment: Let's call this edge $e=${$u,v$}. the cycle is between $u and v$. Since the path between was already existent in $T$ is it correct that the edge that wights more in $T$ is in this path?

Comment: Hmm, this is trickier than I thought!  I don't yet have the answer myself.  The difficult case (that we need to prove cannot exist in any minimal counterexample) is when every edge in the cycle has weight $\le w'_i$: if any edge $w_j$ with $j \ge i$ (not just $w_i$ itself) is in the cycle, then we can pick that edge to delete.

Comment: By changing the minimality requirement to be the number of vertices in $G$, I can show that in any minimal counterexample, $T$ and $T'$ are edge-disjoint: this is because if they share some edge, we could merge its endpoints (in $G$, $T$ and $T'$) to create a smaller counterexample, without destroying the MST-ness of $T$ or the spanning-ness of $T$.  But I don't immediately see how this can be made use of.  (I was hoping for a contradiction by the pigeonhole principle, but for $G$ a complete graph on 4 or more vertices, it's easily possible to have edge-disjoint spanning trees.)

Comment: I'll write here the steps that I went through: 1. I look at the minimal $i$ that satisfies $w'_i < w_i$. 2. I look at the edges of $T$ that are of weight $ \le w'_i$ (there are $i-1$ edges like this) and I look at the edges of $T'$ that are of weight $ \le w'_i$ (there are at least $i$ edges like this). 3. Since a forest with $n$ nodes and $k$ edges has $n-k$ connected components, this sub-forest $T$ has more connected components the sub-forest $T'$. 4.Therefor there are nodes $u,v$ that are connected in the sub-forest of $T'$ but not in the sub-forest of $T$.

Comment: 5.Since $T$ himself is a spanning tree, there exists a path between $u$ and $v$ in $T$, and it has to contain at least one edge with weight $>w'_i$. 6.What is left is to get a contradiction to the fact that $T$ is a minimum spanning tree, and this is what I couldn't manage.

Comment: @GabiG: This looks like a promising approach.  With what you have so far, it would suffice to show that there is always some edge in the sub-forest of $T'$ (which necessarily has weight $\le w'_i$) that will form a cycle containing some edge with weight $> w'_i$ in $T$, since you can then delete the latter edge to get a lower-weight tree -- perhaps you could try induction on the number of vertices in the graph?

Comment: @GabiG: Actually I think you almost have it already!  Call the sub-forest of $T$ $F$, and the sub-forest of $T'$ $F'$.  Instead of letting $u$ and $v$ be arbitrary vertices in different components $F$, require them to additionally be the endpoints of an edge in $F'$.  This is always possible, since on any path in $F'$ beginning in one $F$-component and ending in a different $F$-component, there is at least one *crossing edge* with one endpoint in each $F$-component.  By your step 5, there must be a path in $T$ between $u$ and $v$ with at least one edge of weight $> w'_i$; adding $uv$ => cycle!

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I got it now

Comment: If we take look at the path between $u$ and $v$ in $T$ and remove the "heavy" edge on it then we get two components. Then, there must exist an edge in the cheap path in $T'$ that will reconnect them. If we add it to what's left of $T$ we get a cheaper spanning tree => contradiction to the fact that $T$ is a MST

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix $G$ and $T$, a minimum spanning tree (MST) of $G$ as in the question. Assume weights of all edges are distinct; we will come back to the general case later.

Since all weights are distinct, there is one-to-one correspondence between edges and their weights.

Let $e_i$ be the edge with weight $w_i$ and $e_i'$ be the edge with weight $w_i'$. Let $T_i$ be the graph with edges $\{e_1, \cdots, e_i\}$ for $i\le n-1$. [The proof of Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Minimality) in the case of $G$ proves, in fact, $G$ has a unique MST that will be found by Kruskal's algorithm, because all weights are distinct. Specifically, the case "Otherwise, $e$ is not in $T$" cannot happen.

**Minimality Lemma**. If an edge not in $T_i$ can be added to $T_i$ without creating a cycle, $e_{i+1}$ must not weigh more than that edge.

Proof. Kruskal's algorithm tries adding the edge of the least weight among the available edges repeatedly, thus including $e_1, e_2, \cdots$ to form $T$ in that order. Let us inspect the moment when Kruskal's algorithm adds $e_{i+1}$ to $T_i$. If $e$ is an edge that weigh less than $e_{i+1}$, it must have been tried to be added to $T_k$ for some $k\le i$. Either $e$ was added to $T_k\subseteq T_i$ or a cycle was created at that time, which means adding it to $T_i$ will create a cycle, too. Done.

For any graph $S$, let $p(S)=0$ if $e_1\not\in S$; otherwise let $P(S)$ be the largest index $k$ such that the first $k$ lightest edges in $S$ is the same as the first $k$ lightest edges in $T$. WLOG, let $T'$ be a counterexample such that $p(T')$ is the largest (among all spanning trees of $G$). Let $q=p(T')$.

**Observation**: $w_{q+1}\lt w'_{q+1}$.
Proof. $\{e_1, e_2\cdots, e_q\}\subseteq T'$. Consider $e_{q+1}'$, the next heavier edge in $T'$. The Minimality Lemma tells that $e_{q+1}$ does not weighs more than $e_{q+1}'$. If it weighs the same as $e_{q+1}'$, then it is $e_{q+1}'$, which contradicts to our assumption of $q$ being the largest. So it must weigh less than $e_{q+1}'$. Done.

Since $T'$ is a spanning tree, if we add $e_{q+1}\not\in T'$ to $T'$, we must have created a cycle. Since we do not have a cycle in $T_{q+1}$, there must be an edge $e'\not\in T_q$ in that cycle. The above observation tells us $e_{q+1}$ weighs less than $e'$.

Let $T''$ be $T'$ with $e'$ replaced by $e_{q+1}$. Since $e'$ and $e_{q+1}$ are on that same cycle, $T''$ is also a spanning tree. Since the only difference between $T'$ and $T''$ is one edge of $T'$ is replaced with an edge of smaller weight, $T''$ is also a counterexample. Since both the first $q+1$ lightest edges of $T''$  and that of $T$ are $\{w_1, w_2\cdots, w_q, w_{q+1}\}$, $p(T'')\ge q+1>q$. This contradicts the assumption that $q$ is the largest. Done.

---

How about the general cases when all weights are not distinct?

For any $\epsilon>0$ that is smaller than the minimum positive difference among the original weights, if we subtract $\epsilon/i$ weight from $e_i$ and subtract $\epsilon/(2dn)$ weight from other edges using different positive integer $d$ for different edges, all new weights will be different and, since edges of $T$ are reduced more, $T$ remains to be an MST.

Letting $\epsilon$ go to 0 to take the limit of the inequalities that we have proved in the cases of distinct weights, we will obtain the same inequalities in the general cases.

---

Interested readers may enjoy the following exercise.

**Exercise**. Generalize MST $T$ to minimum-weighted sub-forest.

**Problem**. Can we prove the above generalization directly?

Comment: What is $G'_{p(T')}$?

Comment: I like the direction you're going, of looking for a contradiction to the minimality of the counterexample :)  But I think "the weight of $e'$ must be no less than the weight of $e_{p(T')+1}$" has problems: all we know about $e'$ is that it's not in $\{e_1, \dots, e_i\}$ -- we don't even know if it is equal to $e_j$ for some $j > i$.  If we knew that adding $e'$ to $G_{p(T')+1}$ would result in no cycle, then we could infer things about its weight -- but AFAICT, we don't know this.

Comment: My argument doesn't depend on there being duplicate weights.  Even when weights are all distinct, we can't conclude that the weight of $e'$ must be no less than the weight of $e_{p(T')+1}$.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, surely we can. Check my rephrased answer.

Comment: [The other answer of mine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/109453/91753) indicates a way to do the exercise and solve the problem at the end of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple proof that is built on top of two results.

**The replace-by-lighter-edge algorithm generates a minimum spanning tree (MST).** Start with any spanning tree $H$ of $G$. Find the cycle in $H$ plus an edge $e$ not in $H$. If an edge $t$ in that cycle is heavier than $e$, remove $t$ from $H$ and add $e$ to $H$. Repeat until we cannot any more. Then $H$ is a MST of $G$.
This is proven in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/57486/91753).

**All MSTs of $G$ have the same number of edges with any given weight.**
This is a classic result proven in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2211/91753).

For the sake of contradiction, suppose for some $i$:  $w_i \gt w'_i$. Then the number of edges in $T'$ with length less than $w_i$ is at least $i$. Now apply 
the replace-by-lighter-edge algorithm on $T'$ so that the new $T'$ is an MST. Note that  the number of edges in the new $T'$ with length less than $w_i$ is still at least $i$. However, since all MSTs have the same number of edges with any given weight, $T'$ and $T$ should have the same number of edges with length less than $w_i$, which is false. QED.