# Do the minimum spanning trees of a graph have the same number of edges with a given weight?

Tags: graphs, correctness-proof, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

I'm asking about the answer here:

[Do the minimum spanning trees of a weighted graph have the same number of edges with a given weight?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/do-the-minimum-spanning-trees-of-a-weighted-graph-have-the-same-number-of-edges/2211#2211)

I didn't understand the best answer here

> Choose edge $e \in T_1 \mathop{\Delta} T_2$ with $w(e) = \min W$, that is $e$ is an edge that occurs in only one of the trees and has minimum disagreeing weight. Such an edge, that is in particular $e \in T_1 \mathop{\Delta} T_2$, always exists: clearly, not all edges of weight $\min W$ can be in both trees, otherwise $\min W \notin W$. W.l.o.g. let $e \in T_1$ and assume $T_1$ has more edges of weight $\min W$ than $T_2$.

First of all, what does minimum *disagreeing* weight mean?

> assume $T_1$ has more edges of weight $\min W$ than $T_2$.

Does the above line mean, $T_1$ has multiple edges with weight $\min W$

> Now consider all edges in $T_2$ that are also in the cut $C_{T_1}(e)$ that is induced by $e$ in $T_1$. If there is an edge $e'$ in there that has the same weight as $e$, update $T_1$ by using $e'$ instead of $e$; note that the new tree is still a minimal spanning tree with the same edge-weight multiset as $T_1$. We iterate this argument, shrinking $W$ by two elements and thereby removing one edge from the set of candidates for $e$ in every step. Therefore, we get after finitely many steps to a setting where all edges in $T_2 \cap C_{T_1}(e)$ (where $T_1$ is the updated version) have weights other than $g(e)$.

This paragraph seems to be a problem for me. So, we remove edges with weight $e$ which is also $\min W$ and replace it with $e'$. So we do that for all edge weight $e$ present in $T_1$

> Therefore, we get after finitely many steps to a setting where all edges in $T_2 \cap C_{T_1}(e)$ (where $T_1$ is the updated version) have weights other than $g(e)$.

I didn't understand this line at all. What is supposed to be $g(e)$?

> Now we can always choose $e' \in C_{T_1}(e) \cap T_2$ such that we can swap $e$ and $e'$¹, that is we can create a new spanning tree
>
> $\qquad \displaystyle T_3 = \begin{cases}
>   (T_1 \setminus \{e\}) \cup \{e'\}  &, w(e') \lt w(e) \\[.5em]
>   (T_2 \setminus \{e'\}) \cup \{e\}  &, w(e') \gt w(e) 
> \end{cases}$
>
> which has smaller weight than $T_1$ and $T_2$; this contradicts the choice of $T_1,T_2$ as minimal spanning trees. Therefore, $W_1 = W_2$.

Why is $w(e') \lt w(e)$ here? isnt $e'$ same as $e$ ? and why does  $T_1,T_2$ contradict as minimal spanning trees?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [my answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/101023/) that proves a stronger result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question and this post refers to [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/2211/2) at its version 2.

> First of all, what does minimum disagreeing weight mean?

The better word should have been "distinguishing". If the set of edges of some fixed weight in $T_1$ is different from that of $T_2$, then $T_1$ and $T_2$ disagree on that weight, i.e., that weight is distinguishing the two minimal trees.

> What is supposed to be $g(e)$?

That is a typo. It should have been $w(e)$.

> Why is $w(e') \lt w(e)$ here? isn't $e'$ same as $e$ ? and why does  $T_1,T_2$ contradict as minimal spanning trees?

Let us use a new dummy variable instead of $e'$ for the last part of that answer.

Let $f \in C_{T_1}(e) \cap T_2$. Had $f$ weighed the same as $e$, we should have update $T_1$ by using $f$ instead of $e$. Since we have done all such updates, $f$ must weigh differently from $e$. That is the conclusion in the previous paragraph, "all edges in $T_2 \cap C_{T_1}(e)$ (where $T_1$ is the updated version) have weights other than $w(e)$".

There are two disjoint cases.

- the case when $w(f)\lt w(e)$. Consider the spanning tree $(T_1 \setminus \{e\}) \cup \{f\}$, which is lighter than $T_1$.
- the case when $w(f)\gt w(e)$. Consider the spanning tree $(T_2 \setminus \{f\}) \cup \{e\}$, which is lighter than $T_2$.

In either case, we have found a spanning tree that is lighter than a minimum spanning tree, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I will update [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2211/91753) when the dust is settle here.

Comment: Thanks! I understood everything except this part "Had $f$ weighed the same as $e$, we should have update $T_1$ by using $f$ instead of $e$. Since we have done all such updates, $f$ must weigh differently from $e$". If $f$ was same as $e$, why would we choose $f$ instead of $e$ (even the $e$ is same right?)

Comment: Before the replacement of $e$ in $T_1$ by $f$, $e$ in $T_1$ corresponded to $f$ in $T_2$. After the replacement, $f$ in $T_1$ corresponded to the same edge, $f$ in $T_2$. So each replacement made the difference between $T_1$ and $T_2$ smaller. After all possible replacements had been made, there should have been no pair of $(e,f)$ such that $w(e)=w(f)=\min(W)$, $e\in T_1$, $f\in C_{T_1}(e)\cap T_2$ and there should have no pair of $(e,f)$ such that $w(e)=w(f)=\min(W)$, $e\in T_2$, $f\in C_{T_2}(e)\cap T_1$, either.