# MST Of An Almost Tree

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

A graph $G = (V,E)$ is called an *almost tree* if it is connected and has most $n + c$ edges where $n = |V|$ and $c$ is a small constant number. How would I go about designing an algorithm for a given almost tree graph $G$ with distinct edge weight costs that computes a minimum spanning tree of $G$ in time $O(n)$?

Comment: You can use LaTeX to typset mathematics, rather than doing it manually with italics. I edited to show you how; we also have a [brief tutorial](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: I appreciate it -- looks more appropriate that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the description of a desired algorithm in Python style pseudocode.

```
Generate a spanning tree T of G
Put all remaining edges that are not in T in a list L
For each edge e in L:
  Find the cycle C in the graph that is T plus edge e.
  If e is lighter than the heaviest edge e' in C:
    add e to T and remove e' from T
```

It requires $O(n)$ operations to generate a spanning tree. It requires $O(n)$ operations to find a cycle when you add an edge to a tree and $O(n)$ operations to find the heaviest edge in a cycle. Since there were total $c+1$ edges remaining, where $c+1$ is a constant, the for loop requires $O(n)$ operations. Adding up other operations of small time, we find that the time-complexity of the algorithm is $O(n)$.

The correctness of the above algorithm has been proved in my answer to [turn MST of G to MST of G with one new edge](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/96229/91753). Note that initially T is its own MST.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a new answer because I can't comment yet.

I'm new to graph problems, but I think it is possible to optimise a bit Jonh L.'s answer by finding the cycle in a way that is O(logn) instead of O(n).

Of course, the complexity of the whole algorithm itself remains the same ((c + 1)logn + n is still O(n)), but it's just something I wanted to mention since I took the time study this problem a bit.

Comment: Your answer adds nothing if you don't describe a way to reach such a complexity. Please edit your answer to add those details.

Comment: It can be done using a dynamic tree structure such as a link cut tree or top tree. In fact, the recent paper [Splay top trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.11918) uses _exactly_ the thing we need here as the example that it implements in its accompanying C code.